# cloudinitnocloud userdata is not working in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, cloud-init

My yaml file likes :

```
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1
kind: VirtualMachineInstance
metadata:
  name: m1
spec:
  domain:
    cpu:
      cores: 4
    devices:
      disks:
      - name: harddrive
        disk: {}
      - name: cloudinitdisk
        disk: {}
      interfaces:
      - name: ovs-net
        bridge: {}
      - name: default
        masquerade: {}
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 8G
  volumes:
    - name: harddrive
      containerDisk:
        image: 1.1.1.1:8888/redhat/redhat79:latest
    - name: cloudinitdisk
      cloudInitNoCloud:
        userData: |
          #!/bin/bash
          echo 1 > /opt/1.txt
  networks:
    - name: ovs-net
      multus:
        networkName: ovs-vlan-100
    - name: default
      pod: {}
```

VMI is running and I login the vm , nothing is in directory '/opt'; I find a disk sdb ,I mount sdb to /mnt, I can see file 'userdata', and the content in 'userdata' is right

I don't know where I did wrong

K8S  1.22.10
I also tried the other two methods
1)

```
cloudInitNoCloud:
  userData: |
    bootcmd:
      - touch  /opt/1.txt
    runcmd:
      - touch  /opt/2.txt
```

2. 

```
cloudInitNoCloud:
  secretRef:
    name:  my-vmi-secret
```

I hope the cloudinitnocloud  work, and it can run my command

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem, the docker image that I used doesn't install cloud* package
Kubevirt offical doesn't mention it, I think I can use it directly.